# Submethod isn't updating local instance variable as expected

Tags: java

I've recently started learning Java so this is a beginner's question.
I have the below simple code which I have spent the past hour debugging without success. I feel this touches on a very basic concept of instance variables that I am not fully grasping.

My program creates a GOval object that moves around the screen. Instance variables are used to assign the ball size and starting velocity/direction (defined as randomized x/y coordinates). A while loop in the `run()` program keeps the ball moving.

The goal of my program is to get the moving ball to stay within the window by having it reverse direction as soon as it hits any of the 4 walls of the graphics window. I have no problem getting the ball to bounce off the walls provided the if statements for reversing ball direction are written *inside* the `run()` method. However if I use the same code in a separate method `CheckWall()` instead, the ball *does not* bounce as expected and simply moves off the screen.

Can someone please help me to understand why the sub method approach isn't working as expected? Is my use of instance variables in this case correct?

Note in my below code, I have used "//" to comment out the if statements in the run method that are working properly. These same methods have been copy/pasted into my CheckWall method.

```
public class S7_DebuggingExample extends GraphicsProgram {
    private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
    private static final int BALL_RADIUS = 20;
    private static final double MIN_DX = 2.0; 
    private static final double MAX_DX = 3.0; 
    private static final double MIN_DY = 2.0; 
    private static final double MAX_DY = 3.0;
    private static final double PAUSE = 15.0; 
    private GOval ball;
    private double dx;
    private double dy;

    public void run() { 
        double dx = rgen.nextDouble(MIN_DX, MAX_DX); 
        double dy = rgen.nextDouble(MIN_DY, MAX_DY);

        SetupBall();

        while (true) { 
            ball.move(dx, dy); 
//          if (ball.getX() <= 0 || ball.getX() >= getWidth() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)) dx = -dx;
//          if (ball.getY() <= 0 || ball.getY() >= getHeight() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)) dy = -dy;
            CheckWall();
            pause(PAUSE);
        }
    }

    private void CheckWall() {
        if (ball.getX() <= 0 || ball.getX() >= getWidth() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)) dx = -dx;
        if (ball.getY() <= 0 || ball.getY() >= getHeight() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)) dy = -dy;
    }


private void SetupBall() { 
    ball = new GOval(BALL_RADIUS * 2, BALL_RADIUS * 2); 
    ball.setFilled(true); 
    ball.setColor(Color.RED); 
    double x = rgen.nextDouble(0, getWidth() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)); 
    double y = rgen.nextDouble(0, getHeight() - (BALL_RADIUS * 2)); 
    ball.setLocation(x, y); 
    add(ball);
}
```

Comment: If you have the lines of code inside the run() method, you're changing the variables dx and dy defined inside the run() method whereas if you have them inside the CheckWall() method, you're chaning the instance variables dx and dy defined in the class.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone all the feedback. This was my first ever question on StackOverflow and the community support is simply amazing!

Comment: You can up-vote any of the below answers if they helped you and "mark as correct" the answer that gave you the best solution.

Comment: Just did that thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables dx and dy declared in your class.
The below ones are global and all the methods access these unless they find a local variable with the same name and type. The local variables are chosen over the class variables.

```
private double dx;
private double dy;
```

So outside your method run(), the dx and dy that you use inside run() becomes invalid and the class level variables are used instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables named dx. The function updates the class member variable, but the run method is using the local variables defined in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Checkwall() makes use of the dx and dy variables declared in the class, whereas the run method makes use of the variables *locally* defined in run(). Hence the problem. Just comment out the locally defined run variables and initialize **class members** dx and dy in the SetUpBall() method.